# WPF: How to display a custom font in my EXE when font stored in a DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, user-controls

In my solution I have two projects:

- `Main` is the WPF executable.
- `Lib` is a WPF User Control Library.

*Lib* is set as reference to *Main*.

## In Lib

There are two folders:

- `Views`, containing the UserControl `MyView`.
- `Fonts`, containing the Font `MyFont.ttf`.

I have included the *MyFont.ttf* into *Lib* and set its `BuildAction` to `Resource`.

Here is the XAML-code for *MyView*:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Lib.Views.MyView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lib.Views"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Foo">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#MyFont" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
 
    <TextBlock Text="asdf" Style="{StaticResource Foo}" />
    <TextBlock Text="asdf" />
</UserControl>
```

**Note:** There are two TextBlocks for comparison.

## Result

In the designer of MyView the first TextBlock has the font I want. **Great!**

## In Main

In my `MainWindow.xaml` I have this code to display *MyView*:

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:Lib.Views;assembly=Lib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <lib:MyView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## Result

In MainWindow's designer and in runtime; The font of the first TextBlock in *MyView* don't have the correct font. Instead it has the default font, as the second TextBlock have in *MyView*.

## Problem

I assume this has to do that *MyFont* is not embedded fully/correctly into *Lib* and therefore can *Main* not fetch the font properly.

What could be the problem with this setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the pack URI to refer to the referenced assembly that contains the font file.

```
<Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Lib;component/Fonts/#MyFont" />
```

The pack URI syntax that you use refers to the [local assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#local-assembly-resource-file), which is the `Main` assembly when loading the resource from your host application.

The adapted pack URI specifies that the font is located in the `Lib` assembly. The [`component`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#referenced-assembly-resource-file) specifies that this assembly is referenced from the local assembly, which works both for the `Lib` assembly alone and the `Main` assembly referencing it.

For more information on the pack URI syntax, refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#referenced-assembly-resource-file).

Comment: @Mc_Topaz To answer your comment before about the designer, I tested this both with a .NET Framework and a .NET Core WPF app. Turns out, that the designer in the .NET Framework project does not apply the font, but in the .NET Core project it does. At runtime both work as expected. As the new designer is capable of displaying it, I guess that this might be an issue with the old one.